# Rails view and pulling data within a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<% @blog.blog_comment_types.each do |blog_comment_type| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= blog_comment_type.comment_type_id %></td>
        <td>Comment name goes here</td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

I want to be able to output the comment name based off the comment_type_id.

I an looping through the blog_comment_type table, I want to use the "comment_type_id" column so I can pull from the following table: comment_type which has the name field I want to output.  The comment_type table has an id which is the referenced comment_type_id being looped through.

Is there a best practice in Rails to do so within a view?

Tbl: comment_type
fields:

- id
- name

tbl: blog_comment_type

fields:

- id
- comment_type_id  (this is the matching id in the comment_type table).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails and beyond, the best practice is **not** to do this in a view.  Instead, if you setup your `Blog` object so it knows about the comment types associated with it, then the problem becomes pretty simple:

```
class Blog
  has_many :blog_comment_types
  ....
end
```

then in your view:

```
<% @blog.blog_comment_types.each do |blog_comment_type| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= blog_comment_type.id %></td>
    <td><%= blog_comment_type.name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: But what if the blog, has a blog_id in the Blog_comment_types table.

Basically,
Blog (id, name)
Blog_comment_types (id, blog_id, comment_type_id)
comment_types(id, name, description).

Would I need to do it any differently?

Comment: the blog_comment_types has a comment_type_id being references so it can tie to the comment_types table which holds the 'name' field.         I have the Blog model already setup that way, but it does not seem to also associate the comment_types table.

Comment: Post your models, I think you found the real problem.